# Use python-firefox-selenium to fill form and download redirected page as pdf

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, firefox

I want to automatically download some details from a web page, which has a form to fill up. Upon clicking enter, the page is redirected to another URL, which contains a pdf file. I want to download the pdf file. I tried save as html, but it has no information at all. Also tried to capture the screenshot, but for a single file, it requires more than one screenshots. I want the page to be downloaded as pdf.

1. Tried saving as html - the html file contains no information
2. Tried screenshots - More than one screenshot for a single page - complications
3. Tried pdfkit - it rerenders the url, and thus loses the credentials entered, resulting in an error page.

I understand that it is not easy to emulate the 'save' option of the browser. But unfortunately, that is something i want.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I have faced this issue before and found snippets which I joined to the following code. Instead of displaying the PDF in the browser it will be downloaded.

```
# firefox profile to download PDF
mime_types_pdf = "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml"
mime_types = mime_types_pdf
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mime_types)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", mime_types)
fp.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", mime_types)
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
geckodriver = '[path_to_your_firefox_driver]/geckodriver'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, firefox_profile=fp)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked! I tried setting the profile earlier, but looks like the mime type list was incomplete. Thanks again for your help. I hope this helps others too, who might be having similar issues. Since I am not having enough reputation, I am not able to upvote your answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Glad I could help out with my first post on stackoverflow. Please mark my post as the answer to your question. Happy coding!